# Rcpp error comparing a DateVector element with a Date

Tags: r, rcpp

The following Rcpp function doesn't compile:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool dateProb(DateVector dateVec, Date date) {
  return (dateVec[0] < date);
}
```

I get the error message:

> Use of overloaded operator '<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'typename storage_type<14>::type' (aka 'double') and 'Rcpp::Date)

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't `dateVec[0]` have the type `Rcpp::Date`?

Answer (score 4):

Well, an `Rcpp::DateVector` is not a vector of `Rcpp::Date`s, but is a class derived from `Rcpp::NumericVector` (see [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/6062d561939e72a9a6bbf0d0b3a2311374be3552/inst/include/Rcpp/date_datetime/newDateVector.h#L29)). This makes sense considering R's own internal treatment of date vectors:

```r
pryr::sexp_type(as.Date("2019/05/04"))
# [1] "REALSXP"
```

So, it may seem surprising at first, but is no real impediment. You can just do this:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool dateProb(DateVector dateVec, Date date) {
    Date date2 = dateVec(0);
    return (date2 < date);
}
```

This compiles just fine, and gives the expected answer from R:

```r
x <- as.Date("2019/05/04")
y <- as.Date("2019/05/03")
dateProb(x, y)
# [1] FALSE

dateProb(y, x)
# [1] TRUE
```

If what you actually want is a vector of `Rcpp::Date`s, that can be achieved easily as well using the member function `getDates()`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool dateProb(DateVector dateVec, Date date) {
    Date date2 = dateVec(0);
    std::vector<Date> newdates = dateVec.getDates();
    Rcpp::Rcout << (newdates[0] < date) << "\n";
    return (date2 < date);
}

/*** R
x <- as.Date("2019/05/04")
y <- as.Date("2019/05/03")
dateProb(x, y)
dateProb(y, x)
*/

> x <- as.Date("2019/05/04")

> y <- as.Date("2019/05/03")

> dateProb(x, y)
0
[1] FALSE

> dateProb(y, x)
1
[1] TRUE
```

Or by just specifying that as your input:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool dateProb(std::vector<Date> dateVec, Date date) {
    return (dateVec[0] < date);
}

/*** R
x <- as.Date("2019/05/04")
y <- as.Date("2019/05/03")
dateProb(x, y)
dateProb(y, x)
*/

> x <- as.Date("2019/05/04")

> y <- as.Date("2019/05/03")

> dateProb(x, y)
[1] FALSE

> dateProb(y, x)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice patient answer. We have that in other cases too:  conversion which do require to/from conversion to `SEXP` "generally work" but the compiler sometimes needs some help. As such the assigning of a `DateVector` element to a `Date` makes comparison easier.  (As an aside `DateVector` is a `NumericVector` but `Date` is also just an S3 wrapper around a single numeric.)